# Is the functor category of a small category into a topos itself a topos?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I am reading the book "Sheaves in Geometry and Logic" by MacLane and Moerdijk.

Early in the book, the authors show that $Sets^{\mathscr{C}^{op}}$ where $\mathscr{C}$ is a small category is an elementary topos.

**My Question: Is it true, more generally, that $\mathscr{E}^{\mathscr{C}^{op}}$ where $\mathscr{E}$ is a topos, itself is a topos?**

I am scratching my head and to me, at least so far, it seems that if $\mathscr{E}$ is Boolean then yes. If this is true: is being Boolean a necessary condition?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being boolean is neither necessary nor sufficient.
(What would the subobject classifier of $\textbf{FinSet}^\omega$, where $\omega$ is the preorder category $\{ 0 \to 1 \to 2 \to \cdots \}$ be?)
What is sufficient is that the category be internalisable into the topos, because we have the following:

**Theorem.**
If $\mathcal{E}$ is a topos and $\mathcal{C}$ is an internal category in $\mathcal{E}$, then the category $\textbf{Psh} (\mathcal{C})$ of internal presheaves on $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathcal{E}$ is also a topos.

In the first place, what does it mean for an ordinary category $\mathcal{C}$ to be internalisable into a topos $\mathcal{E}$?
There are a few ways you could define it, but the point is that we want the (ordinary) category of functors $\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op} \to \mathcal{E}$ to be equivalent to the (ordinary) category of internal presheaves on some internal category in $\mathcal{E}$.
For example, $\omega^\textrm{op}$ is not internalisable in $\textbf{FinSet}$ – not surprising, considering it has infinitely many non-isomorphic objects!
But usually there is no problem, because:

**Theorem.**
Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal.
If $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to a category with $< \kappa$ morphisms, and $\mathcal{E}$ is a topos in which $\coprod_{i \in I} 1$ exists for all sets $I$ of cardinality $< \kappa$, then $\mathcal{C}$ is internalisable in $\mathcal{E}$.
In particular, if $\mathcal{C}$ is essentially small and $\mathcal{E}$ is a cocomplete topos, then $\mathcal{C}$ is internalisable in $\mathcal{E}$.

That said, internalisability is not necessary for $\mathcal{E}^{\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}}$ to be a topos either.
For example, $\textbf{FinSet}^{\omega^\textrm{op}}$ is a topos even though $\omega$ is not internalisable in $\textbf{FinSet}$.
Similarly, $\textbf{Set}^{\textbf{ON}^\textrm{op}}$ is a topos, where $\textbf{ON}$ is the preorder category of all small ordinals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Is it known what the necessary and sufficient condition is?

Comment: The only difficulty is the existence of a subobject classifier. But it is hard to give any necessary and sufficient condition for that which isn’t just a paraphrase.

Comment: I see. Thanks :).

Comment: Sorry, I mean power objects in general, not just the subobject classifier. (But the subobject classifier is a power object.)